# jquery mobile loadPage running on phonegap fails with Error Loading Page

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

im testing this on nexus s with ics
phongap version 1.4
jqm version 1.0.1

i tried following these guidelines,
    1) added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in server app running at local ip http://192.168.1.132/orderpage, tried with both html and json reponses
    2) may be this not needed but still i've set `$.support.cors` and `$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages` to true;
    3) `phonegap.xml` origin is set to *
    4) also put a `super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);`

this works fine on browser but i keep getting error loading page on phonegap no matter what!
am i missing something in phonegap app? loading local file works fine `$.mobile.loadPage('order.html')` but

```
$.mobile.loadPage( "http://192.168.1.132/orderpage", { showLoadMsg: true } );
```

fails with `error loading page`

the app im trying to build is totally depended on server side content, how can i safely load external content with ajax calls or loadpage()

and how to debug to check if phonegap is even making the request to network?

any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

thank you,

Answer (score 1):

I found I need to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

To my AndroidManifest.xml

HTH